# Setting a className when using Dropdown.item as Link

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I am using code below to avoid " nested" JS error and keeping Link properties inside a react-bootstrap Dropdown.

```
<Dropdown.Item className="dropdown-item" as={Link} href={`/example`}>
    Example
</Dropdown.Item>
```

Result is as follow on the DOM:

```
<a href="/example">Example</a>
```

Problem is: `className="dropdown-item"` has been ignored.

How could I get this result: `<a href="/example" class="dropdown-item">Example</a>` while keeping the code "react-friendly"?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that demonstrates that you're using Next's `Link`, which is a critical detail to be able to properly address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `bsPrefix` to override the bootstrap styling ...

[Docs reference ...](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/#dropdown-item-props)

[image: In Docs ...]

A sample e.g. here in below link - see dropdown first item's bg color... Please fork it for reference

[image: E.g. here]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I already tried using `bsPrefix` while using `as={Link}` but this didn't work. Moreover, in your sample, you do not use Link from 'next/link' as a custom element type. That is what I am using.

Comment: It would only work for the bootstrap component tmk ... so yeah i thought it was same ... sorry no idea on it to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap it around.

```
<Link to={`/example`}><Dropdown.Item className="dropdown-item">
    Example
</Dropdown.Item></Link>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Problem here is that this solution will provoke a JS error, as I'ma referring to the first line of my post : `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.`

Comment: even if you remove the "as={Link}" ? in the dropdownitem?

Comment: Yes ! complete code is: `<Link href={"/example"}><Dropdown.Item className="dropdown-item">Example</Dropdown.Item></Link>`.
Note that I'm using Link from next/link and that `to` attribute does not exist on the last version I'm using. so that is why I'm using `href` instead. Transpilation will convert Link to a `<a></a>` and Dropdown.Item to another `<a></a>`, which will lead to JS Error nested a